# Objective-C restart iphone or possibly another method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, restart, reboot

I read that there was no method to restart the iPhone (at least that will go through the app store), so I am wondering if you have any other ideas.  Basically, at my desk, I receive "No Service"... When I go out to my car (in a service area), I remain in No Service without being able to make a call until I restart my iPhone.  I've tried respringing winterboard, I've tried airplane mode on/off and that doesn't work either.  The only way I've found is to restart the iPhone completely.  Does anyone else have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try making an app that runs as `root` and calls `system("shutdown -r now")`.

Comment: @zneak Jailbreaking notwithstanding, there's no way to run an app as the root user.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: he's jailbroken, otherwise he wouldn't be using Winterboard.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Thought it said "springboard" on first read.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is right on the money. Nothing you can do about this particular problem outside of jailbreaking.