# Locking a jail break iPhone on App exit

Tags: iphone

I want to create an app on jail broke iphone which, on exit should lock the iPhone automatically. Can anyone please give me any piece of code which can help in this regard.

Thanks,

Comment: What does the jailbreak-part have to do with it? Your only going to get downvotes for that here, since pretty much all users here try to make a (honest) living out of programming.

Comment: Goodness @Joetjah, who said that someone writing a jailbreak app is NOT making an honest living? It seems a pretty honest question that Yasar is asking.

Comment: @Dave Arkell: I said neither of that. I'm just asking what the jailbreak-part has to do with it, and I stated a fact about the community here. I'm not the one who downvoted, I'm just hinting to leave the information away which may cause that... Take it easy

Comment: ok, fair enough. Sorry @Joetjah. I think jail break, because it's probably only possible using a private api and therefore won't get accepted in the app store. Is that correct @Yasar?

Answer (score 0):

I have only come across  a way to prevent the iPhone from locking automatically, I dont really think that there is a way to do what you are looking for.

In my opinion, even if it is possible then it would be through some private API which would cause your app to be rejected anyway.

Just for your reference, the code to prevent the iPhone from autolocking when an app is running is given below.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES
```

You might want to check out other related posts before actually posting a question :)

Comment: Private API(s) or some scripting can do the trick for me. This app is just for me so worries about app store.The only thing i need is that i have 3 buttons in my app, 1 for lock, 1 for reboot, and 1 for shut down. In one of the post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613852/objective-c-restart-iphone-or-possibly-another-method" zneak commented that "Try making an app that runs as root and calls system("shutdown -r now")".But i have no idea how i can create an app which runs as root. and how can i call system("shutdown -r now"). So if anyone can help me in this regard.